# Unit testing with classes

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++

Write a unit test for addInventory(). Call redSweater.addInventory() with parameter sweaterShipment. Print the shown error if the subsequent quantity is incorrect. Sample output for failed unit test given initial quantity is 10 and sweaterShipment is 50:
Beginning tests.
   UNIT TEST FAILED: addInventory()
Tests complete.
Note: UNIT TEST FAILED is preceded by 3 spaces.

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class InventoryTag {
public:
   InventoryTag();
   int getQuantityRemaining() const;
   void addInventory(int numItems);

private:
   int quantityRemaining;
};

InventoryTag::InventoryTag() {
    quantityRemaining = 0;
}

int InventoryTag::getQuantityRemaining() const {
   return quantityRemaining;
}

void InventoryTag::addInventory(int numItems) {
   if (numItems > 10) {
      quantityRemaining = quantityRemaining + numItems;
   }
}

int main() {
   InventoryTag redSweater;
   int sweaterShipment = 0;
   int sweaterInventoryBefore = 0;

   sweaterInventoryBefore = redSweater.getQuantityRemaining();
   sweaterShipment = 25;

   cout << "Beginning tests." << endl;

   // FIXME add unit test for addInventory




   cout << "Tests complete." << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how to write the unit test for addInventory in this question, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you understand this part: *"Call redSweater.addInventory() with parameter sweaterShipment."*?

Answer (score 0):

In an industry setting unit tests are typically done using some kind of unit testing framework, [Google Test](https://github.com/google/googletest) for example. If you're using visual studio you might checkout the basics of unit testing in VS [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/getting-started-with-unit-testing).

The beginning of your question reads like this is a school project or something. If that's the case then you probably don't want either of those options.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to include other libraries?

Personally, I would write unit tests by using the cassert library. You can use it like this after including it:

```
assert(1+1==2)
```

And it will throw an error if it's not true.